# Spectral family of multiplication operator $T:L^{2}[0,1]\rightarrow L^{2}[0,1]$ defined by $Tx(t)=tx(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Consider the multiplication operator $T:L^{2}[0,1]\rightarrow L^{2}[0,1]$ defined by $y(t)=Tx(t)=tx(t).$ Then $\sigma(T)=\sigma_{c}(T)=[0,1]$ and the corresponding spectral family is defined by
$$E_{\lambda}x= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   if  & \lambda<0 \\
             \\ v_{\lambda} &  if & 0\leq\lambda\leq 1 \\
             \\ x &  if  & \lambda \geq 1 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
where
$$v_{\lambda}(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x(t) &   if  & 0\leq t \leq \lambda \\
             \\ 0 &  if  & \lambda<t\leq 1. 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

First, I've proved that operator multiplication $Tx(t)=tx(t)$ is linear, bounded and self-adjoint. Even more, such operator has no eigenvalues. Then residual spectrum $\sigma_{r}(T)=\emptyset$ and $\sigma_{c}(T)=\sigma(T).$

Computing $m=\displaystyle\inf_{||x||=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle=t=\displaystyle\sup_{||x||=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle=M$ and since $T$ is self-adjoint we can conclude $\sigma(T)=[0,1]$ because $t\in[0,1].$

I'm stuck proving that $\{E_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda}$ is the spectral family, defined as above, of such operator.

I've seen in some cases this can be computed directly depending of the operator: if $T$ is the null operator or the identity such spectral family is easy to find, but in this case I can't see it.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectral family $E_{\lambda}$ is multiplication by a characteristic function:
$$
           E_{\lambda}f = 0,\;\; \lambda \le 0 \\
           E_{\lambda}f = \chi_{[0,\lambda]}f,\;\;\; 0 \le \lambda \le 1, \\
           E_{\lambda}f = f,\;\; 1 \le \lambda.
$$
If you unravel your definition, you'll have the same thing. Notice that
$$
                E_{\lambda+\Delta\lambda}f-E_{\lambda}f = \chi{[\lambda,\lambda+\Delta\lambda]}f
$$
$$
             T(E_{\lambda+\Delta\lambda}f-E_{\lambda}f) \approx \lambda(E_{\lambda+\Delta\lambda}f-E_{\lambda}f)
$$
$T$ has approximate eigenvalues $[0,1]$, but no actual ones.

Comment: Thanks to answer @DisintegratingByParts. I can't see how do you deduce the form of the spectral family. I know that $E_{\lambda}$ is the projection of the Hilbert space onto the null space $N(T_{\lambda}),$ but I can't see the way to get the characterization that you have given,

Comment: @Squird37 : It helps to see the continuous case and the discrete case. Everything else is a mix of those two. You have eigenvalues and approximate eigenvalues, and that's all you get with a selfadjoint operator.